# .toggleClass() adds specific clicked link class

Tags: jquery

So if I want `toggleClass()` to add the class of a specific item that was clicked how would I do this?

I know it's like a basic syntax thing, but I'm pretty new to `jQuery` so any help would be appreciated. More specifically, I have something like this:

```
<div class=zoom></div>

<div>
    <div class=grid info a1></div>
    <div class=grid info a2></div>
    <div class=grid info a3></div>
</div>
```

---

```
$(".grid.info").click(function() {
    $('.zoom').toggleClass("A1 or A2 or A3 depending on which was clicked");
});
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Does it have to be a class? It would be easier if you used a data attribute.

Comment: I just need the specific information of which div was clicked so that I can match the content within the 'zoom' div.  So if div a1 was clicked, content a1 will be shown within 'zoom'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it positional if it always will be in the order of `a1, a2, a3, etc..`:

```
$(".grid.info").click(function() {    
    $(".grid.info").not(this).each(function(){
        var classToRemove = "a" + ($(this).index() + 1);
        $('.zoom').removeClass(classToRemove);
    });

    var classClicked = "a" + ($(this).index() + 1);
    $('.zoom').toggleClass(classClicked);
});
```

---

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6QsWD/) - toggle ax class of clicked div, remove all others previously clicked ax

---

The above only works if the order always matches, but if your divs are in a different order and then the `index()` becomes useless and you have to look at adding possibly data-attribute, like this:

```
<div class="grid info a3" data-class="a3">3</div>
<div class="grid info a2" data-class="a2">2</div>
<div class="grid info a1" data-class="a1">1</div>
```

Using a data-attribute as already suggested would be more reliable and you script only slightly changes to this:

```
$(".grid.info").click(function() {    
    $(".grid.info").not(this).each(function(){
        var classToRemove = $(this).data("class");
        $('.zoom').removeClass(classToRemove);
    });

    var classClicked = $(this).data("class");
    $('.zoom').toggleClass(classClicked);
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rXPPL/) - Using data attribute instead

---

Comment: What if I want to make it more robust and include different letters?  Or pass the title itself?  Would you advise I use a single ID tag so as not have to parse through the different classes?

Comment: @user2059518: I edited my answer to also include a complete data-attribute solution in case the order is not the same. If you are using data-attributes you can add any name of a class into it and it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".grid.info").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('.zoom');
    });
```

.toggleClass( className ).. you can check it [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) . So you can use the ClassName that you want to toggle as parameter of toggleClass

Comment: Remove the . as it already taking a class. write like this $(this).toggleClass('zoom');

Comment: He doesn't want to toggle the `zoom` class, he wants to toggle `a1`, `a2`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Example of how to do this on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htmled/dkjX5/).

HTML:

```
<div class="zoom">
    Zoom
</div>

<div>
    <div class="grid info a1">1</div>
    <div class="grid info a2">2</div>
    <div class="grid info a3">3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.zoom {
    display: none;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".grid.info").click(function() {
    $('.zoom').toggle("show");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, this is just about perfect.  Is there any way to pass the class of the link that was clicked so that i can make the 'zoom' div contain images specific to the links that was clicked?  So if a1 was clicked then a1 content would be displayed.  Lemme know if that makes sense

Comment: `so that i can make the 'zoom' div contain images specific to the links that was clicked?` that is completely different than asking how to add the a class from a clicked div to another div. You should probably add this important piece of information to the question.

Comment: It's in his sample code: `"A1 or A2 or A3 depending on which was clicked"`

Comment: The question asks how to toggle classes a1, a2 or a3 on the `zoom` div depending on which one was clicked, the answer only toggles a show class not a1, a2 or a3... I'm lost to how this is just about perfect?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the help. A deleted post seemed to be getting pretty close.  They wrote:

    $(".grid.info").click(function() {
   
        var classClicked="a" + $(this).index();
 console.log(classClicked);
 $('.zoom').toggleClass(classClicked);
    });

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="zoom"></div>

<div>
    <div class="grid info a1" data-class="a1"></div>
    <div class="grid info a2" data-class="a2"></div>
    <div class="grid info a3" data-class="a3"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".grid.info").click(function() {
    $('.zoom').toggleClass($(this).data("class"));
});
```

Comment: Don't forget the quotes around the parameters to the `class` attribute.

Comment: +1 Using a data attribute would eliminate the issue of order. However, your answer is missing to remove any previously added class but it gets the general idea across.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl The question didn't say anything about removing classes of the non-clicked divs.

Comment: Hence +1 as originally I thought the same. I assumed the whole logic was about toggling the class on the zoom across the board only afterwards based on the comments OP left throughout on the other answers and the question. OP mentioned in a comment the desire to match the content of `zoom` to the clicked div, which would make less sense if all other classes would have stayed. That is just how I interpreted it which could have been completely false I guess.

Answer (score 0):

While you've already accepted an answer, I was intrigued by the potential of a solution to your problem, so, I came up with this:

```
$('.grid').click(function(){
    var theClass = /(a\d)/.exec(this.className).shift(),
        curClass = /(a\d)/.exec($('.zoom').get(0).className),
        exClass = curClass !== null ? curClass.shift() : '';
    console.log(theClass === exClass);
    if (exClass == theClass) {
        $('.zoom').removeClass(theClass);
    }
    else {
        $('.zoom')
        .removeClass(exClass)
        .addClass(theClass);
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hRbas/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`regexp.exex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
- [`Array.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)